Ingesting data from external table into ADX table automatically
I have external table in ADX pointing to SQL database. I want to ingest data into ADX internal table when data is ingested in SQL database table.
I am using these external tables in materialized views as look up tables. External tables not supported by materialized views so I manually inserted data from external table to internal table using .set-or-append. and then using ADX internal tables in materialized views.
But I want to make an automated process with in ADX where SQL table and ADX table are in sync when new data is updated in SQL database table.
It should be done with in ADX but not using other tools like ADF, Function App, Logicapp etc.
Is there any option we can do within ADX?

Can someone please suggest...??

Brahmaiah, I don't think this is possible as of now. As you mentioned, materialized views do not support external tables, nor do update policies support external tables. So the only way is using scheduling tools like ADF.

thanks @Werner for your support and help.
